# SetEnvIfExpr with response header

Tags: apache-2.4

I want to set a environment variable when a specific response header has a value.

But when I make this it doesn't set the variable.

```
Header add X-foo "bar"
<If "resp('X-foo') == 'bar'">
    Header add X-test-foobar "foobarnew"
</If>
```

It doesn't set the header X-test-foobar.

Maybe I don't have correctly understand how does it should work. I'm not really fluent in apache programming... I think that programming is not sequential in apache environment but I don't know how to set an env variable with the content of the response header.

Thanks for any help,

ZS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`If`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#if)  may be evaluated too early in Apache's processing to use attributes of the response. The documentation isn't clear and I can't find that elsewhere right now.

But the [`Header`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_headers.html#header) directive is processed late, so it can use the response. You just need to add the `expr` condition to it:

```
Header add X-test-foobar "foobarnew" "expr=resp('X-foo') == 'bar'"
```

Comment: It is clear from documentation here: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/expr.html. Various elements, like CONTENT-TYPE are not available during <If>. See the answer I just posted: https://serverfault.com/a/898657/396475

Comment: Header is processed late by default, just before returning the response. See the documentation at https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_headers.html saying: "mod_headers can be applied either early or late in the request. The normal mode is late, when Request Headers are set immediately before running the content generator and Response Headers just as the response is sent down the wire. Always use Late mode in an operational server."