# How to add a header in .htaccess bases on filetype (mime type)?

Tags: apache-2.4, .htaccess, centos7, http-headers

I would like to add two extra HTTP headers to all responses that are of filetype (mime type) text/html, but not other files.

The current headers (edited):

```
curl -I https://www......

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Fri, 23 Feb 2018 20:43:15 GMT
Server: Apache
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache
Vary: Content-Type,Accept-Encoding
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Content-Language: de-DE
```

The `<If>` statement I tried is not working (my idea was to check for `text/html`, and if that is set, then also add two extra headers with `Header set`.

I have checked multiple sources like [here on apache.org](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/expr.html#examples), but cannot seem to find the answer.

This is one of the things I've tried that seems most logical to me. Do a check for a current header; if result is true then add extra headers.

```
<If "%{HTTP:Content-Type} in { 'text/html' }">
Header set Header1 test
Header set Header2 test
</If>
```

But I do not know if this ENV is taken from the request or response header.

Does anyone know of a way to achieve this -- add custom HTTP header in the response based on mime type?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will probably need to match on something else than the content-type because it is probably set later and hence not available there.

The documentation at https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/expr.html explains your problem:

```
CONTENT_TYPE    The content type of the response (not available during <If >)
```

I would try doing things with just the `mod_headers` module. Look at examples here: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_headers.html

So I would suggest something like:

```
Header always set Header1 Value1 "expr=%{CONTENT_TYPE} == text/html"
```

If that does not work because CONTENT_TYPE is not set, you will need to match like on the extension stored in REQUEST_URI.

Comment: Thank you. OK, will try that "expr=%{CONTENT_TYPE} == text/html" . The other thing: there are no "filename extensions" to match to -- that's the issue :-).

Comment: The test on CONTENT_TYPE should work when in `Header` because it is very last in the chain, just before sending the output. It does not in `If` because it is executed too early in the response.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you all, this has indeed worked for me (adding a condition at the end of the `Header Set` command):

```
Header always set X-TEST VALUE-XYZ "expr=%{CONTENT_TYPE} == 'text/html; charset=UTF-8'"
```

I think this should also work without the `always`, have not tried that yet.